# Class Pointer as a Data Member of Another Object

Tags: c++

just getting an odd error and I'm not entirely sure as to why.

I have 4 files (two headers and two implementations). The issue is inside the headers:

The main file ONLY includes the Station.h, which is why Stations.h is included inside it.

Station.h

```
#ifndef STATION_H
#define STATION_H
#include "Stations.h"

#include <string>

enum PassType{student, adult};

class Station{

        std::string station_name;
        unsigned int student_passes;
        unsigned int adult_passes;

    public:
        Station();
        void set(const std::string&, unsigned, unsigned);
        void update(PassType, int);
        unsigned inStock(PassType) const;
        const std::string& getName() const;

};


#endif
```

Stations.h

```
#ifndef STATIONS_H
#define STATIONS_H
#include "Station.h"

namespace w2{

    class Stations{

    Station *station;

    public:
        Stations(char *);
        void update() const;
        void restock() const;
        void report() const;
        ~Stations();

    };

}

#endif
```

It doesn't know what Station is. I'm getting the following error:

```
./Stations.h:9:2: error: unknown type name 'Station'; did you mean 'Stations'?
        Station *station;
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Is there more than one file named Station.h and you're getting the wrong one? Any namespaces involved?

Comment: Are there any `#ifdef` lines to prevent multiple inclusion? Please include the entire contents of the files.

Comment: @ R Sahu - There is in both headers.

Comment: @dlf Yes there is namespaces involved. I'll update the post.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper You generally shouldn't put an #include inside a namespace. That said, the code as shown should still work. Is `Station` defined inside a `w2` namespace too? Because that would explain the error you're seeing.

Comment: @dlf Oh sorry, the include is outside the namespace. No, there are no other namepsaces involved. Just in that one header. Yes, exactly. That's why I'm a little lost here.

Comment: is that all your code or are you hiding smthg?

Comment: @SomeDeveloper You could try putting a blatant compile error in Station.h. If you don't get an error from it, it means the compiler isn't including what you think it is.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper The problem is that Station.h includes Stations.h, so the compiler sees Stations before Station.

Comment: @dlf gosh, alright. The problem is that the main.cpp only inludes Station.h. So I need to bring in Stations.h somehow without using it in main.cpp. (This is an assignment of mine).

Comment: @SomeDeveloper Can't main.cpp #include both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `#include`ing Stations.h in Station.h. As a result, the compiler sees `class Stations` before `class Station`. In this case, it doesn't appear that `Station` requires `Stations`, so you can simply remove the include.

If `Station` *did* need to know about `Stations`, then you'd have to use a forward declaration in one of the headers or the other (and be careful not to use the forward-declared class in a way that required the full definition).

Comment: Got it! Disregard my last comment. Huge typo! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put a semicolon after you declare the Stations class:

```
class Stations {
     Station *station;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to do the forward declaration.
Remove the #include "Stations.h" from the Station.h

```
#ifndef STATIONS_H
#define STATIONS_H
#include "Station.h"

namespace w2{
    class Station;
    class Stations{

    Station *station;

    public:
        Stations(char *);
        void update() const;
        void restock() const;
        void report() const;
        ~Stations();

    };

}

#endif
```